# How to add unit tests in Eclipse for a managed ARM C project?

Tags: c, eclipse, unit-testing, embedded

I've got a managed Eclipse project that uses the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain to compile for an ST microcontroller. What I want to do now is, unit test the code in that project. The framework I want to use for unit testing is Google Test.

I tried creating a second Eclipse project for the unit tests, that uses the standard GNU toolchain. Like this:

Project1 (ARM)
|---src

Project2 (Desktop)
|---test

The problem with that is twofold:

1. The second project doesn't have access to the source code of the first project (obviously). Therefore I tried creating a static library from the first project for testing purposes, which leads to the second problem.
2. The Library created from the first project isn't compatible with the second project, because it uses the GNU ARM embedded toolchain instead of the standard GNU toolchain.

To solve the second problem I added a build configuration to the first project to try and compile it with the right toolchain. That didn't work out though.

Another path I went was to have the unit tests in the same project as the actual code and use a build configuration to create an executable for unit testing. Something like this:

Project
|---src
|---test

That didn't work out as well and it kind of seems like it's the same problem as with the first approach anyway.

The problem isn't unit testing in itself. I know how to use Google Test for testing regular C projects in eclipse.

How is unit testing an embedded project usually approached with managed projects in eclipse? Is it possible at all? If so, is it a good way to do it or should I write my own makefile to accompilsh this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that using eclipse auto generated makefiles, you have to create a Build Configuration for each build (one for target and one for the desktop), accordingly:

- Project1, will have to be built as a static library for both platforms. It will contain your application in a platform independent manner.
- Project2 will have to be build only for Desktop, it will have tests and tests main, also will link to Project1 library.
- A Project3 (with main and platform dependent code) will have to be created and build a an elf or bin, linking to Project1 library for target platform.

It can get more complicated if you decide to run tests on target platform as well;

I have two examples/templates where you can get based, but they are not related to eclipse:

1. Build with Makefiles with msp430 toolchain, CppUTest as test framework.
   https://github.com/felipe-lavratti/UnitTestingEmbeddedC-Demo1
2. Build using Scons, tests are run in both platforms, dependencies and CppUTest as unit testing framework.
   https://github.com/felipe-lavratti/UnitTestYoutubeVideos